# Compass watch - ignore files in config.rb

Tags: sass, compass-sass, watch, guard

this is my dir structure

```
css/
sprites/_sprite.scss
scss/important.scss
scss/file1.scss
...
scss/file5.scss
scss/file6.scss
scss/file7.scss
scss/file8.scss
scss/file9.scss
scss/file10.scss
```

I want to be able to use

```
compass watch
```

to monitor changes to scss/important.scss file ONLY.
I know about

```
compass watch scss/important.scss
```

But I want to achieve the same just using a config file conf.rb so I can use compass like that

```
compass watch
```

Why I want to do this? Because I want to run compass via Guard. I know that in Guard I can watch certain files but it doesn't help me as compass always rebuilds all the scss files regardless of what Guard watches.

The reason I want to build only one scss file is because I use compass to generate PNG sprite and it takes 5 seconds for each scss where that sprite is imported. Way too long to use Guard with LiveReload (11 x 5s !!!).

prefixing the other SCSS files with "_" is not an option.

I just want compass to watch one file without having to specify this file as a command line argument

Comment: Can you explain why prefixing with "_" is not an option?

Comment: And by the way, I remember there's an option called `sass_path`, it should allows you to specify an specific file when watching/compiling.

Comment: @nightire **sass_path** is essentially sass_dir and it points to ALL the files in that directory

Comment: @nightire I can't use "_" prefix for ./scss/file*.scss-s. There is multiple SCSS files in /scss/ directory. For my production build I need all of them to be compiled what will generate 11 individual CSS files. But during development I only need one of them "/scss/important.scss"

All the files are in GIT. I can't just rename them temporarily during development as there is many other developers working on those files and with GIT we check in changes quite often.

Comment: OK, I have two ideas maybe can help you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have two ideas maybe can help you.

1. move your sass files to another directory except for main.scss, name that directory whatever you want, for example: `includes`. Then put `additional_import_paths = 'path/to/includes'`, leave `sass_dir` as it used to be. Finally in your `main.scss` import other files. Now, compass knows the dependencies for `main.scss` but won't compile those files because they stay in an independent directory.

   But there's a littler issue left: how to compile them in production environment? Well, compass allows us to specify environment variable like `environment = :production` (and its default value is `:development`). With this help, you can write your `sass_dir` as `sass_dir = (environment == :production) ? 'path/includes/main' : ['path/includes/main', 'path/includes/others']`, and execute command: `compass compile -e production` at the final stage.
2. Write a bash alias like: `alias mycompass="compass watch scss/main.scss"`, and you know it. use `mycompass` for your own work, leave compass as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

What I eventually did was:

I run

```
compass watch scss/important.scss
```

in one console and

```
guard -i
```

in another console. I set up Guard to watch on CSS file cachanges and do LiveReload. I removed compass from my guard configuration. Now it all works as I expected except I have to keep two terminals open.